# Python Random Question program sometimes provides unanswerable questions

Tags: python

below is a python function that will provide 1 question. However some times, the question it provides will have a recurring number that can't be answered. For example 100/9. What can I edit so that the answer will always be within 2 decimal places if applicable?

Can this be resolved by converting something into a float and forcing 2 decimal places?

```
import random

def genKnow():
  questions = {}
  score = 0

  for i in range (1):
    int_a = random.randint(0,100)
    int_b = random.randint(0,100)
    operators = ['+','-','*','/']
    operator_value = random.choice(operators)
    question = str(int_a)+''+str(operator_value)+''+str(int_b)
    answer = eval(question)
    question+=': '

    questions.update({question:str(answer)})

  for q in questions.keys():
    user_answer = input(q)

    if questions.get(q) == str(user_answer):
      score+=1
      print("Well Done!")
    else:
      print("Bummer!")

  print("you got "+str(score)+" Congrats!")
  input("Press enter to close this program")
  genKnow()

print("Welcome to the game")
genKnow()
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried thinking of a solution, do you have any idea of where to begin? Be careful about using `eval()`. I would recommend learning about string formatting, it will simplify some parts of your code. Finally, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

For divisions only you can cheat, and do the sum in reverse. Take a random value and a random *result* and apply the inverse of the operator to get the other factor of the sum. For example, with your random numbers `100` and `9` and the operator `/`, you get

```
___ / 100 = 9
```

where `9` is the answer. Thus, the unknown that you want to ask in the question is the inverse operation `100*9`, so the end result is

```
900/100 = ____
```

and you keep `9` secret as it's the answer.

For multiplications, additions, and subtractions you do not need change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you generate the question, if the division operator is chosen, to something like a*b / a = b

e.g.
choices are (100, 9, '/')
question = str(int_a*int_b)+' '+str(operator_value)+' '+str(int_a)
answer = int_b

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming you mean by unanswerable questions is that the answer is not a integer if that is the case you could have something in your code to see if the number is an integer or not and if it isn't just generate the question again i think that would fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I came back to the code about an hour later and I came up with my own solution.
Thank you everyone for your help, but my solution was rather simple now that I think about it.

The solution is:

```
answer = round(eval(question),2)
```

To round the answer up to 2 decimal places, and as such during runtime you must give the answer to 2 decimal places should the need arise. When it comes to whole numbers, that has remained unchanged.